# Use of ω in AS3 grammar?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

Some ECMAScript 3 statements have automatic semicolon insertion when followed by line breaks, which cause the following example to not be a call (e.g., `f()`):

```
f
(0)
```

So do some AS3 statements... But I don't get why [AS3 specification](http://bloople.net/as3ls) uses ω (a greek symbol) in the section **15. Statements** to define the `Statement` unterminal.

The section pre-defines the symbol ω:

```
ω = {abbrev, noShortIf, full}
```

Following this, defines productions of `Statement`<sup>ω</sup> and `Substatement`<sup>ω</sup>. E.g.:

Statement<sup>ω</sup>

- IfStatement<sup>ω</sup>
- SwitchStatement
- ContinueStatement Semicolon<sup>ω</sup>

I'd like to know what <sup>ω</sup> suffix means. It's not used in "every" statement listed in both `Statement` and `Substatement`. But some months ago I saw a bit of ES4 draft spec' and it also had this greek suffix. Anyone knows?

Comment: In physics it would be `ω = 2π / T` :)

Comment: @JonasW Err... Idk even know what this is for, cuz I never needed that so far.

Comment: Just sharing some unneccessary knowledge...

Comment: @JonasW So, it's [angular fequency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency)... So, yeah... never heard bcuz I lost 3 school grades and am still student, but... it's interestin, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is their way to compress similar wordings with suffixes. Say "statement<sup>ω</sup>" stands for either "statement<sup>abbrev</sup>", "statement<sup>noShortIf</sup>" or "statement<sup>full</sup>". The letter itself has no special meaning.

Comment: These suffixes might be based in Java spec', too.